# NSItemProvider to PHAsset

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, phasset, phphotolibrary

I'm building an app and I need to get the `PHAsset` of an image from the `NSItemProvider`.

The `NSURL` I'm getting is for example:

```
file:///Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/84BDFE8E-127E-4677-83B8-208227CCBC16/data/Media/PhotoData/OutgoingTemp/A4D845E7-17E3-4C35-8993-027092D3604A.JPG
```

And I need to be able to get a PHAsset from that URL so I can use PHPhotoLibrary to work with the image.

I tried:

```
let imageAssetToDelete = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([imageURL], options: nil)
```

Where imageURL is an `NSURL` with the previous posted URL but it always returns an empty array.

Comment: If you are testing on iPhone device, your photos may store on iCloud. So, you should download first.